# Select and update dropbox menu

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to select an item from a list box (table element which in fact is a textarea) using VBA (Excel).

I'm able to select the item (by changing the Value) but the problem is that when I press the button "Save" the site returns the following error :

> The Status Reason field requires a value when the status is either pending or resolved. Select the status reason from the menu. (ARERR 1291220)

I think this happens because the list box does not get updated.

Listbox (which is not a real Listbox):

```
<textarea title="" class="text sr " id="arid_WIN_1_1000000881" style="left: 117px; top: 0px; width: 223px; height: 21px;" rows="1" cols="20" wrap="off" readonly="" arencryptdataatrest="0" arautoctt="400" arautocak="0" mdd="1" mstyle="2" armenu="SYS:RSN:StatusReason-Q-HPD-HelpDesk" maxlen="40"></textarea>
```

My code:

```
Dim post As Object, evt As Object
Set evt = .Document.createEvent("keyboardevent")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False

Set post = .Document.getElementByID("arid_WIN_1_1000000881")
    post.Value = "No Further Action Required"
post.dispatchEvent evt
```

Please let me know if you need further information.

[Update]

Below is the full code of the table that shows after pressing the listbox

```
<div class="MenuOuter" style="left: 338px; top: 127px; width: 225px; height: 114px; visibility: inherit; z-index: 100007;" armenuelementserial="0"><div class="MenuScrollUp" style="width: 223px; visibility: hidden;">▲</div><iframe src="https://extranet.inditex.com/arsys/resources/html/Blank.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: absolute;"></iframe><div class="MenuTableContainer"><table class="MenuTable" style="width: 223px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody class="MenuTableBody"><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">Automated Resolution Reported</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="Automated Resolution Reported"></td></tr><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryNameHover" nowrap="">Customer Follow-Up Required</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSubHover" arvalue="Customer Follow-Up Required"></td></tr><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">Temporary Corrective Action</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="Temporary Corrective Action"></td></tr><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">Future Enhancement</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="Future Enhancement"></td></tr><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">Monitoring Incident</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="Monitoring Incident"></td></tr><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">No Further Action Required</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="No Further Action Required"></td></tr><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">(clear)</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue=""></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="MenuScrollDown" style="width: 223px; visibility: hidden;">▼</div></div>
```

And a screenshot showing the listbox.

[image]

I want to update the value of the Status Reason field after changing the value (which I'm already able to do), note that the Status Reason items are updated after the item chosen in Status list box (Status list box is an input item and I can successfully edit the value and update it).

**[Update 1]**

Now I'm able to find the drop-down list which appears after pressing the button near the Status Reason text area.

First I click on the button to see the drop-down list with

```
.Document.getElementsByClassName("df arfid1000000881 ardbnzID_Status_Reason Char")(0).getElementsByClassName("btn btn3d menu")(0).Click
```

Now I successfully find the correct row inside the table with

```
.Document.getElementsByClassName("MenuTable")(0).Rows(5)
```

But when I do .Click nothing happens, I tried also with FireEvent and Selected = True (the last one gives me an error)

**[Update 2]**

When I click the button to open the drop-down list, there's is a GET callback, same happens when I click an item from the drop-down list.

[image]

```
<ExpandMenu>

Request URL: https://extranet.inditex.com/arsys/BackChannel/?param=283%2FExpandMenu%2F35%2FSYS%3ARSN%3AStatusReason-Q-HPD-HelpDesk6%2Fitxars13%2FHPD%3AHelp%20Desk6%2Fitxars28%2FSYS%3AStatus%20Reason%20Menu%20Items103%2F1%5C1%5C1%5C4%5C1%5C1%5C1000000101%5C2%5C4%5C13%5CHPD%3AHelp%20Desk%5C4%5C1%5C1%5C1000000186%5C99%5C7%5C4%5C1%5C1%5C7%5C2%5C6%5C1%5C4%5C1%5C1%5C1000004827%5C2%5C6%5C0%5C0%2F1%2F01%2F05%2F1%2F1%2F715%2F1%2F10%2F4%20Resolved5%2F1%2F1%2F62%2F0%2F2%2F0%2F2%2F0%2F2%2F0%2F2%2F0%2F2%2F0%2F&sToken=MCNY-LTDA-W512-T7V8-J5GS-JHN4-58XW-VYAK
```

```
<GetEntryList>

Request URL: https://extranet.inditex.com/arsys/BackChannel/?param=266%2FGetEntryList%2F6%2Fitxars13%2FHPD%3AHelp%20Desk18%2FBest%20Practice%20View6%2Fitxars28%2FSYS%3AStatus%20Reason%20Menu%20Items0%2F71%2F1%5C4%5C1%5C99%5C1000000881%5C1%5C1000000009%5C4%5C1%5C2%5C4%5C13%5CHPD%3AHelp%20Desk%5C1%5C1000000101%5C15%2F1%2F10%2F100000088131%2F1%2F26%2FNo%20Further%20Action%20Required5%2F1%2F1%2F45%2F1%2F1%2F01%2F01%2F21%2F715%2F1%2F10%2F1000004336&sToken=MCNY-LTDA-W512-T7V8-J5GS-JHN4-58XW-VYAK
```

Comment: Try to manually select the value and check what changes occur in the HTML using developer tools. It is hard to get an idea from one line of HTML code. I suggest you try to provide some more HTML and VBA code may help us to understand the issue properly.

Comment: I updated the main thread with more information.

Comment: I checked your updated code and found that there is no JS event mentioned in the code. I assume that when the user selects the option it will change the class in HTML code which shows the selected value. I suggest you check the change in dev tools. It can give the idea of how values get selected. Then we can try to perform a similar thing via VBA code.

Comment: I noticed that when the mouse is over an item in the list, the attribute class value (of the td elements) changes from **MenuEntryName** to **MenuEntryNameHover**, so I changed manually the attribute to simulate the mouse over (which is working because I can see the blue color selection) but when I do Click nothings changes, the list stays open and the item is not clicked.

Comment: It also depends on which language this site was developed. I can see code does not has any JS events. Can you see any JS code or referenced JS files? It is hard to guess because we don't know how this site was developed and how it is working.

Comment: Hi @Deepak-MSFT please see the [Update 2] in the main thread. Thank you for your support!

Comment: You can try to create an HTTP request and try to send it. you can find the example in this link. https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/ Let us know whether it helps to fix your issue. I did not get any other solution for this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for the hint. I've tried with the HTTP request, and even if is sent correctly, the site is still giving me that error. Could be of any help if I send you the entire source code of the page?

Comment: This is the link where you can find the entire source code of the page: https://paste.ee/r/WvLdA/0

Comment: It is hard for us to check that long code. I suggest you create a support ticket for Microsoft. An engineer will be assigned to look into your issue. Thanks for your understanding.